# scrapy crawl no response

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I just learn python and web scraping. I follow a tutorial to do web scraping. However, the output is different from the tutorial, that lead to error when I run the code. the tutorial said

> Once you have created the project you will change to the newly created directory and write the following command:
>
> `[scrapy genspider aliexpress_tablets](https://www.aliexpress.com/category/200216607/tablets.html)`

The ideal results should be:
[image: the first image]

But my result is:
[image: that]

I think I do not change it successfully. I do not know how to get the same result with the tutorial. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[...]` and `(...)` characters. That looks like a mistake in the [tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/making-web-crawlers-scrapy-python), although their screenshot does show the correct command without those characters.

Your command should be:

```
scrapy genspider aliexpress_tablets https://www.aliexpress.com/category/200216607/tablets.html
```